# socket timeout: It works, but why and how, mainly the select() function?

Tags: c, sockets, select, timeout

Here is part of the code I'm using now.

```
fd_set fdset;
struct timeval tv;
int flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL);    
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

FD_ZERO(&fdset);
FD_SET(sockfd, &fdset);
tv.tv_sec = 3;          
tv.tv_usec = 0;

if (select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv) == 1)
{
    int so_error;
    socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;
    getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);
    if (so_error == 0) {
        cout << " - CONNECTION ESTABLISHED\n";
    }
} else
{
    cout << " - TIMEOUT\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```

I don't clearly understand how the select() function works, here in pseudo code is what I really want to do,

```
    bool showOnce = true;

    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) 
    while(stillConnecting) /*Some kind of flag of connection status*/
    {
        if(showOnce)
        {
            showOnce = false;
            cout << "Connecting";
        }
    }

    if(connected) /*Another possible flag if it exists*/
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

Is there anyway to implement this pseudo code, do these flags exist?

EDIT: Also why is sockfd+1 in the select function in the code above? Why is one added to it?

Comment: What did you learn when you read the documentation for `select()`?

Comment: I didn't really learn yet, sorry, I mostly do embedded development and needed to write a quick pc program for simple comm. I'm currently reading a msdn page on the select function as I write this comment. I guess I could use it to check the status of the socket like in the pseudo code. Trying to figure out how though. I'm getting there :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual: `man 2 select`:

1. `nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.`, that's why `sockfd + 1`.
2. `select()` returns the number of descriptors which trigger a requested event. Only one descriptor is given, so select can return at most `1`.
3. So if after 3 seconds, the given timeout, nothing happens, `select()` does not return `1`, so you consider it a timeout. The case of an error `-1` is not handled.

Comment: `man 3 select` means "section 3 (library functions) of the manual". You should actually read section 2, the system calls.

Comment: `man man` explains it. It is the section in the manual, in case the given keywords is present in more than one section. - `3` stands for _Library calls (functions within program libraries)_.

Comment: I fixed my text. `man 3 select` actually shows `FD_SET(3)` manual which also contains `select()`. Guess that's where I got the 3 from.

Comment: I'm reading the documentation on it now, what you said "Only one descriptor is given, so select can return at most 1." are you referring to the third option in the select() call above?  select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv), the &fdset. So is this function checking if the socket is writable? If I did this: select(sockfd + 1, &fdset2, &fdset, NULL, &tv) would it check for writability and readability returning a possible range of values from -1 to 2?    Also is this how I could check those "flags" I was referring to?

Comment: `nfds` is the first parameter of `select()`. If you do not have the manual installed, read it online: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html.

Comment: What I understood from the MAN page is this method call select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv) will return when sockfd is writable or if it timesout, whichever comes first, right?