# Close thread when waiting for data in recv

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, recv

I have a server, which creates a thread for every client. This is the thread function, where my program waits for data to be send. I need somehow to close this thread if no data is send in 5 seconds.  I tryied with that signal / alarm combination, and somehow works, but the rest of thread function is continuing printing errors, because the sClient(socket) is closed. How can i make this work, or maybe an other solution?

```
void time_out() {
  char r = "-1";
  printf("Time out");
  send(sClient, &r, 10, 0);
  close(sClient);
}

void* thread(void *arg) {
  sClient = (int)arg;
  int size;

  char* buffer = (char*)malloc(300);

  signal(SIGALRM, time_out);
  alarm(5);

  if (recv(sClient, (char*)&size, sizeof(int), 0) < 0) {
    printf("Error when getting length \n");
  }

....
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but it sounds like you want to open a thread for a client, wait for 5 seconds, and then close it if the client has not sent data within that time. Is that correct?

Comment: yes it is :). How can i do it ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you decided to use the SIGALRM approach? Why not just `sleep(5)` in your thread before doing the receive call? Is it because recv blocks?

Comment: I would use `select` with a timeout of 5 seconds and only try the `recv` if `select` indicates there is data waiting on the socket.

Comment: may also just close the socket in main thread. This will end the blocking recv will return WSAEINTR. This way the thread of the non-responding client will terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should open the thread, wait for 5 seconds, and then check the sClient for data. If there is no data, then you can close the thread immediately. Otherwise, if there is data, you can call recv to actually get the data.

To do this, you can use the `select` call with a timeout to check for new data on a socket.

(See "[socket timeout: It works, but why and how, mainly the select() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932512/c-socket-timeout-it-works-but-why-and-how-mainly-the-select-function)" for how `select` with a timeout works.)